# errors when trying to work with threads

Tags: c++, c++11

Hello everybody hope all is well.  I am trying to work with threads in c++.  I compiled the code and got the following error messages.

```
C:\Users\Peretz\Documents\keylogger\KeyConstants.h|183|warning: unknown escape sequence: '\|' [enabled by default]|
C:\Users\Peretz\Documents\keylogger\Timer.h|10|error: 'thread' in namespace 'std' does not name a type|
C:\Users\Peretz\Documents\keylogger\Timer.h||In member function 'void Timer::SleepAndRun()':|
C:\Users\Peretz\Documents\keylogger\Timer.h|25|error: 'std::this_thread' has not been declared|
C:\Users\Peretz\Documents\keylogger\Timer.h||In member function 'void Timer::Start(bool)':|
C:\Users\Peretz\Documents\keylogger\Timer.h|71|error: 'Thread' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\Peretz\Documents\keylogger\Timer.h|71|error: 'thread' is not a member of 'std'|
C:\Users\Peretz\Documents\keylogger\Timer.h||In member function 'void Timer::Stop()':|
C:\Users\Peretz\Documents\keylogger\Timer.h|82|error: 'Thread' was not declared in this scope|
||=== Build failed: 5 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

I looked on Youtube for threads in c++ and threads in c++11 but could not find an answer.  Please explain why there are these errors.

```
#ifndef TIMER_H
#define TIMER_H

#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

class Timer   
{    
    std::thread Thread; 
    bool Alive = false;
    long CallNumber = -1L;

    long repeat_count = -1L;
    std::chrono::milliseconds interval = std::chrono::milliseconds(0);
    std::function<void(void)> funct = nullptr;

    void SleepAndRun ()
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(interval);
        if (Alive)
        {
            Function ()();
        }
    }

    void ThreadFunc ()
    {
        if (CallNumber == Infinite)
            while (Alive)
                SleepAndRun ();
        else
            while (repeat_count--)
                SleepAndRun ();
    }

    public:

    static const long Infinite = -1L;

    Timer () {}
    Timer(const std::function<void(void)> &f) : funct (f) {}
    Timer(const std::function<void(void)> &f,
          const unsigned long &i,
          const long repeat = Timer::Infinite) : funct (f),
        interval (std::chrono::milliseconds(i)), CallNumber (repeat) {}

    void Start (bool Async = true)
    {
        if (IsAlive ())
            return;
        Alive = true;
        repeat_count = CallNumber;
        if (Async)
            Thread = std::thread (ThreadFunc,this);
        else
            this->ThreadFunc ();
    }

    void Stop ()
    {
        Alive = false;
        Thread.join ();
    }

    void SetFunction (const std::function<void (void)> &f)
    {
        funct = f;
    }

    bool IsAlive () const
    {
        return Alive;
    }

    void RepeatCount (const long r)
    {   
        if (Alive)
            return;
        CallNumber = r;
    }

    long GetLeftCount () const
    {
        return repeat_count;
    }

    long RepeatCount () const
    {
        return CallNumber;
    }

    void SetInterval (const unsigned long &i)
    {   
        if (Alive)
            return;
        interval = std::chrono::milliseconds(i);
    }

    unsigned long Interval () const
    {
        return interval.count();
    }

    const std::function<void(void)> &Function () const
    {
        return funct;
    }
};
#endif
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you turn C++11 on in the compiler?

Comment: And your command to run this is? ...

Comment: Also, add `#include <functional>` to support `std::function`.

Comment: Have a look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47347/follow-up-timer-utilizing-stdfuture

Comment: I turned on C++11 in the compiler, am using the Windows API(-mwindows) and updated my version of CodeBlocks(the IDE I am using) but the code is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
error: 'thread' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
```

Whichever compiler you're using (looks like Visual C++) doesn't support `std::thread` (which is part of C++11).